# Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'. javax/persistence/Entity

Tags: java, groovy, grails-3.0, intellij-15

Here is My build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {        
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.5.0'
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate:4.3.10.5"

    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.5.2.RELEASE"

}

version "0.1"
group "testapp"

apply plugin: "spring-boot"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "asset-pipeline"
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"

    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"






    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"

    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"

    // Note: It is recommended to update to a more robust driver (Chrome, Firefox etc.)
    testRuntime 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.44.0'

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}
```

after grails run-app getting below error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.

  > javax/persistence/Entity
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.
  | Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Comment: What versions of grails, groovy and JDK? Did you try a `grails clean` and then the `grails run-app` again?

Comment: jdk-8u65, grails-3.1.0.RC1,intelijIdea-15.
I am tried commandLine and intelijIdea, both are same error "classNotFound Exception javax/persistence/Entity"

Comment: Grails Version: 3.1.0.RC1
Groovy Version: 2.4.5
JVM Version: 1.8.0_66